# Nuxt, VueJS This must be called within a setup function

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've got a project. It's currently available on a certain website. I need to implement some changes. When I download a project from gitlab and run it throws me an error:***This must be called within a setup function.***

path: .nuxt/composition-api/index.js

```
const useContext = () => {
  const vm = CompositionApi.getCurrentInstance();
  if (!vm)
    throw new Error("This must be called within a setup function.");
  return {
    ...(vm[globalNuxt] || vm.$options).context,
    route: CompositionApi.computed(() => vm.$route),
    query: CompositionApi.computed(() => vm.$route.query),
```

What is wrong?

I need to run the project to make some changes but can't deploy it on my local server.

Update:
useContex is in default.vue

```
...
setup (_, { isServer, refs }: any) {
    // console.info(context)
    // const refs = context.refs
    const { store } = useContext()
    const { scrolllock } = scrollLock(store)
    const locationName = computed(() => store.getters.locationName)
    const location = computed({
      set (val: boolean) {
        store.dispatch('setLocationModal', val)
      },
      get () {
        return store.getters.locationModal
      }
    })
...
```

**cmd output when I'm trying to go the site**

```
[Vue warn]: [vue-composition-api] already installed. Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) should be called only once.


 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "Error: This must be called within a setup function."                    22:50:04

found in

---> <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>


 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "Error: This must be called within a setup function."                    22:50:05

found in

---> <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>


 ERROR  [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "Error: This must be called within a setup function."                    22:50:24

found in

---> <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
       <Root>
```

Comment: The error suggests that you're using `@vue/composition-api` in addition to `@nuxtjs/composition-api`. You only need the latter, and you wouldn't need to call `Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)` with that module.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. I deleted Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI) form composition-api.js and it didn't help. Maybe there's another way to start it? I need to change only scss files.

Comment: There's not enough context to determine the problem. Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Answer (score 6):

From my experience, npm can't install `@nuxtjs/composition-api` older versions, or something like that, so I did uninstall its older version and install the new version and it's worked

here is what I've done

```js
rm -rf node_modules && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm uninstall @nuxtjs/composition-api && npm i @nuxtjs/composition-api && npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of things, it seems you

- You created another plugin for the VueCompositionAPI when it is installed already e.g `@nuxtjs/composition-api`

I would advise you to remove any other composition-api from your project and stick to the latest version of the official [`@nuxtjs/composition-api`](https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/setup) with `Vuex v4` for Nuxt 2

In the latest version of `@nuxtjs/composition-api`, you could use

```
const store = useStore();
// OR
const { store } = useContext();
```

NOTE: You have to define the helper functions like `const router = useStore()` directly inside your `setup()` function, and not inside your method, to avoid `This must be called within a setup function` error.

For those that want to use `route`

> To smooth your upgrade to Nuxt 3, it is recommended ***not to*** access `route`, `query`, `from` and `params` from `useContext` but rather to use the `useRoute` helper function.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I faced this error while converting a mixin file into a composable function. It got fixed when I used `useContext` inside the function and not out.

Instead of this

```js
import { useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
const { $device } = useContext()

export const usePreload = () => {
... // rest of the code
}
```

Changed to this

```js
import { useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'

export const usePreload = () => {

... // rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what happened there. I deleted that repository and cloned it again.
Next up I did this:
`npm init`
and then
`npm run dev`
And it works.